# Build on Ubuntu Touch - toxcore

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling, toxic

I want to install [Toxcore](https://github.com/TokTok/c-toxcore/blob/master/INSTALL.md#quick-install)
on Ubuntu Touch emulator.
There are some dependencies in order for that to run though.

```
build-essential
libtool
autotools-dev
automake
checkinstall
git
yasm
libsodium13
libsodium-dev
```

How can I install those and successfully build toxcore?

I'm new to Ubuntu touch and Linux in general.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this by accident. Check out those scripts I wrote a while ago while trying to write a Tox client for Ubuntu: https://github.com/nikwen/ubuntu-toxcore-cross-compilation-scripts

They will allow you to cross-compile toxcore from an Ubuntu desktop computer.

You will have just to adjust the SDK version number in the setup script and possibly the git repo in `build-toxcore.sh`.